# mysqldump and "Can't find record" table errors on restore

Tags: database, mariadb, mariadb-10.3, mysql-backup

I've been using the following mysqldump command to backup my mariadb databases for several years, and never had a problem restoring. Until today. Here is the command I've been using for one of the databases:

```
/usr/bin/mysqldump --complete-insert --compress --add-drop-table --lock-tables --verbose -u root -ppass --log-error=backup-mydb-2022-10-29-2240418-error.log --result-file=backup-mydb-2022-10-29-2240418.sql mydb
```

The error file shows no errors.

```
-- Retrieving table structure for table xu33gc_dictionary_letters...
-- Sending SELECT query...
-- Retrieving rows...
```

I used the following for restore:

```
mysql -u root -ppass mydb < backup-mydb-2022-10-29-2240418.sql
```

Upon restore, it resulted in the following:

```
ERROR 1032 (HY000) at line 9413: Can't find record in 'xu33gc_dictionary_letters'
```

A simple grep through the sql backup above finds:

```
grep xu33gc_dictionary_letters backup-mydb-2022-10-29-2240418.sql
-- Table structure for table `xu33gc_dictionary_letters`
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `xu33gc_dictionary_letters`;
CREATE TABLE `xu33gc_dictionary_letters` (
-- Dumping data for table `xu33gc_dictionary_letters`
LOCK TABLES `xu33gc_dictionary_letters` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `xu33gc_dictionary_letters` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `xu33gc_dictionary_letters` (`id`, `letter_name`) VALUES (1,'A'),(2,'B'), 
(3,'C'),(4,'D'),(5,'E'),(6,'F'),(7,'G'),(8,'H'),(9,'I'),(10,'J'),(11,'K'),(12,'L'), 
... [cut for brevity]
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `xu33gc_dictionary_letters` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

So the table is there. What could be the problem? Even more strange is that I ran the same backup again, then the same restore, and it produced a different problem:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 21042: Can't create table `mydb`.`xu33gc_tj_notification_user_exclusions` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
```

I'm also backing up using mariabackup, but it's much more involved and difficult to restore because of having to do all the differentials.

Comment: I could be totally wrong in my answer. What does `show create table xu33gc_tj_notification_user_exclusions` show? Which MariaDB 10.3 version? Is possible that its generating an output it cannot parse.

Comment: Including the definition of the table it has a FK relationship to could also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is:

- The lack of `--single-transaction` as a `mysqldump` option means that an inconsistent snapshot is being created. As theorized below:
- At some point while during the dump, a row and its foreign key where deleted.
- `mysqldump` completed one table without the row, and the other table with the row.
- on attempting to restore, at the point it enables FKs again, there is no complete relationship hence the `ER_KEY_NOT_FOUND` error.

Note: could have been an insert too, the insert was done on a table which wasn't backed up, and then on the FK with the backup completed, generating the same inconsistency on restore.

So importantly, use `--single-transaction` with backups.

Comment: Very good, thanks. I will test that. Isn't that what --lock-tables is for, to prevent changes from occuring during the dump process?

Comment: Your right, `--lock-tables` explicitly `LOCK TABLES .... ` (all tables accessed in the backup). If its all innodb, `--single-transaction` leaves data writeable while still obtaining a backup. The problem might be elsewhere.

Comment: Instead of trying to fix this method, what should I be doing instead? How is mysqlbackup intended to be used properly?